# Allow multiple users to fill form in MS Access or HTML Form based submission

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'll summarize the operation to give you a background. 
I've an Access database in place with forms wherein a user inputs with diverse fields. This file is hosted on a shared network for my organization. The database is split between backend and frontend.

Issue(s): 
- Multiple user cannot access a single form and simultaneous entries are not allowed. 
- In case, if the file is opened by mistake it will prevent to enable submissions for other users on the network.

I am not sure if this will work as I am a newbie in Access. But can we create a HTML based form which will fill the tables in Access? If yes, kindly help in creating one. If not, kindly suggest an alternative.

Sample table attributes:

```
Date Name Type Remark
```

Comment: If properly designed, multiple users can input data.

Comment: Hi @Gustav thank you for your reply. Could you please be more specific on the part of designing? - Thanks

Comment: I could, but that is way to broad a topic for this forum. You could try at [Experts Exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com).

Comment: Each user should run their own copy of frontend.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same type of setup I use at my company. We have one backend (all the tables) and a frontend (queries, forms, reports, etc). The way to allow multiple users to work with the database is to have each user run their own instance on their computer ie have them copy/paste the frontend to their local desktop. Another thing to keep in mind is that the tables must be set up with primary key and autonumber field to prevent users from accessing and editing the same record.